# How to put the author of the post in the comments?

Tags: posts, functions, customization, comment-form, comments-template

I need to put the name of the author who wrote the post and I can't find the solution.

EXAMPLE:

Rachel [06/03/21] : Commented in the post "How to be a Web Designer", written by: **POSTAGE AUTHOR** - Test Comment

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'user_id' => bp_current_user_id(),
        'number' => 20, // how many comments to retrieve
        'status' => 'approve'
        );

    $comments = get_comments( $args );

    if ( $comments )
    {
        $output.= "<ul>\n";
        foreach ( $comments as $c )
        { 
        $output.= '<li>';
        $output.= $c->comment_author;
        $output.= ' [';
        $output.= mysql2date('d/m/y', $c->comment_date, $translate);
        $output.= '] ';
        $output.= ' : ';
        $output.= '<a href="'.get_comment_link( $c->comment_ID ).'">';
        $output.= get_the_title($c->comment_post_ID);
        $output.= "</a>";
        $output.= ' - ';
        $output.= $comment->user_id;
        $output.= $c->comment_content;
        $output.= "</li>\n";
        
        }
        $output.= '</ul>';

        echo $output;
        
        
    } else { echo "No comments made";}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it's the shortest way, but it works)

**Get post author id**

```
$post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $c->comment_post_ID );
```

**Get author data by id**

```
$post_author_display_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post_author_id );
```

**Try this shorter version**

```
$output.= get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', get_post_field( 'post_author', $c->comment_post_ID ) );
```

Check documentation page which data is available with [get_the_author_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/)

Comment: Thank you Anton! It worked great!

Comment: Glad it helped you. Approve this answer if your problem is solved, please. It will remove your question from unanswered list. Thanks)

Comment: Hello Anton! Thank you again. Can you help me with this issue?

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/390145/how-to-put-the-avatar-and-url-buddypress-profile-of-the-commenter-in-the-wordp